# Why it stop at the make phase when install mesos?

Tags: installation, mesos

I tried to install mesos, I follwed the instructions from the official website. When I type the make after the configure, after some time, it stoped for a long time and no error output, I feel very confused about this. The log where it stoped is as follows:

```
no_3rdparty_la-master.Tpo -c master/master.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o master/.libs/libmesos_no_  
3rdparty_la-master.o libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=
\"mesos\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"mesos\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.21.0\" "-
DPACKAGE_STRING=\"mesos 0.21.0\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -     

DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"mesos\" -DVERSION=\"0.21.0\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1    
-DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 
-DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -
DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -
DHAVE_LIBZ=1 -DHAVE_LIBCURL=1 -DHAVE_APR_POOLS_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBAPR_1=1 -    
DHAVE_SVN_VERSION_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBSVN_SUBR_1=1 -DHAVE_SVN_DELTA_H=1 -
DHAVE_LIBSVN_DELTA_1=1 -DHAVE_LIBSASL2=1 -DMESOS_HAS_JAVA=1 -
DHAVE_PYTHON=\"2.6\" -DMESOS_HAS_PYTHON=1 -I. -Wall -Werror -  
DLIBDIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" -DPKGLIBEXECDIR=\"/usr/local/libexec/mesos\" -
DPKGDATADIR=\"/usr/local/share/mesos\" -I../include -
I../3rdparty/libprocess/include -
I../3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty/stout/include -I../include -
I../include/mesos -I../3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty/boost-1.53.0 -
I../3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty/picojson-4f93734 -
I../3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty/protobuf-2.5.0/src -
I../3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty/glog-0.3.3/src -
I../3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty/glog-0.3.3/src -
I../3rdparty/leveldb/include -I../3rdparty/zookeeper-3.4.5/src/c/include -
I../3rdparty/zookeeper-3.4.5/src/c/generated -
I../3rdparty/libprocess/3rdparty/protobuf-2.5.0/src -
I/usr/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -
pthread -g1 -O0 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -std=c++11 -MT 
master/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-master.lo -MD -MP -MF 
master/.deps/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-master.Tpo -c master/master.cpp -o 
master/libmesos_no_3rdparty_la-master.o >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Have anyone met this issue? How to solve it please?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about the machine you are building on? Compilation of some source files requires larger amounts of RAM with certain compilers. I suspect your compilation was killed by your OS.

Comment: Knowing the command to invoke `make` would also help. It looks like you are redirecting stdout/err to /dev/null so it won't print any error/warnings either. Also, how long is "long time"? As in a few seconds, minutes, ...?